# Programmatically get a full page html rendering of a route/page

Tags: 9

We provide our content via APIs. At times we use the Views Restful approach, and at times the JSONAPI.

We need to add an API field on nodes that is a full HTML rendering of that node's page according to the theme (technically I just need ... but I'll take the whole doc if I can get it).

I have tried a number of approaches:

I tried using the renderer service. It renders full html from the html.html.twig template but items such as blocks on the page are missing. I guess it doesn't have all the context it needs.

```
$view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
$content = $view_builder->view($node);
$build = [
  '#type' => 'html',
  'page' => [
    '#type' => 'page',
    '#theme' => 'page',
    '#title' => $node->get("title")->value,
    'content' => $content,
  ],
];
$page = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);
```

Very similarly I tried using twig_render_template. It similarly renders full html but items such as blocks on the page are missing.

```
$markup = twig_render_template(drupal_get_path('theme', 'neato') . '/templates/base/html.html.twig', array(
  'page' => [
    '#type' => 'page',
    '#theme' => 'page',
    '#title' => $node->get("title")->value,
    'content' => $content,
  ],
  // Needed to prevent notices when Twig debugging is enabled.
  'theme_hook_original' => 'not-applicable',
));
$body = (string) $markup;
```

As a separate approach, I tried to make a 'subrequest'. With this approach, I get the rendered HTML but it causes fatal early rendering errors such as "A stray renderRoot() invocation is causing bubbling of attached assets to break."

```
$kernel = \Drupal::service('http_kernel.basic');
$sub_request = \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::create("/node/".$value->_entity->id(), 'GET');
$subResponse = $kernel->handle($sub_request, \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
$html = $subResponse->getContent();
```

I even tried to mimic the full drupal 'bootstrap'

```
$autoloader = require '/app/web/autoload.php';
$sub_request = Request::create("/node/".$node->id(), 'GET');
$site_path = DrupalKernel::findSitePath($sub_request);
$kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($sub_request, $autoloader, 'prod');
$sub_response = $kernel->handle($sub_request, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
$html = $sub_response->getContent();
```

I am open to any and all pointers and suggestions. I really appreciate it.

Comment: just as a probably "not-so-performant" and non-drupal way, use a file_get_contents on the page url ...

Comment: PS: i just stumbled across `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot(` in some of my code, maybe it helps instead using `renderPlain`

Comment: Normally you don't need to render variables at all. But if you need to, then use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->render()`. The two methods above are only for specific use cases, not for normal page renderings.

Comment: Agreed. This is not how pages are normally rendered. It's an edge case for my spec.

I tried \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot and render() many ways. It never had all the context. I got the HTML skeleton of the page but blocks and such were still missing. I found you would have to mimic the full Drupal request, which is complex, and started to feel like a worse direction.

We went a similar path to @johnSmith's rec of using file_get_contents(). When nodes are saved, we use httpClient to make a 2nd request to the site. That response is saved in a field and included in the API. Thx!!

Answer (score 2):

We went a similar path to @johnSmith's rec of using file_get_contents(). Thanks!

**TL;DR;**
When nodes are saved, we use httpClient to make a 2nd request to the site. That response is saved in a field and included in the API. Thx!!

**Details**

- A new field was added to the associated content types. This field will be used to store the rendered page HTML.
- A custom module was written. When nodes of the associated content types are created or updated, a subsequent request is made using httpClient. This request is made to the node page. That HTML response is saved in the new field.

  //We have saved the configured domain name in which to make this render request to in Drupal's config.

  $config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('myApi.static_server_settings');

  $domain = $config->get('myApi.theme_domain');

  //Request this node's rendered page

  $nid = $node->id();

  $client = \Drupal::httpClient();

  $request = $client->get($domain.'/node/'.$nid);

  $render = (string) $request->getBody();
- Our API was extended to include this field. As a fallback, when the API runs, if the new field is empty that same subsequent httpClient request is made on the fly.
- We built a batch process that updates the 'rendered page' field for all the content. This can be run if the theme is updated. We may eventually trigger it from our theme-building scripts/gulp/CI stuff.